# Six members of a family go to the cinema and all want to be seated on the same row next to each other. The row contains 20 seats.

Tags: combinatorics

Could someone help me with this?

I couldn't fit the whole question in the title.

Six members of a family go to the cinema and all want to be seated on the same row next to each other. This row contains 20 seats.
Find the number of ways they can arrange themselves.

I've scratched the surface of the question by identifying 6! as the ways in which they can arrange themselves. But I'm not sure how to make it so that they will be next to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Now have them lock arms and decide where the leftmost member will sit.

Answer (score 0):

Since they all want to sit next to each other, all acceptable arrangements will have some number of "empty" seats to their left, then 6 occupied seats, then some number of "empty" seats to their right. These two sets of "empty" seats will always sum to 20 - 6 = 14. Therefore the number of acceptable seating arrangements can be partitioned into sets labeled by every distinct possible number of "empty" seats to the left (or, equivalently, right), like

(0): FFFFFF00000000000000

(1): 0FFFFFF0000000000000

(2): 0FFFFFF0000000000000

.

.

.

(14):00000000000000FFFFFF

The *total* number of  possible arrangements is the sum of the number of possible seating orders in every one of these 15 available sets (not 14, since there are 14 + 1 = 15 elements in the set (0 ... 14) ) , and in every such set, the family of 6 have 6! distinct possible seating orders.  Therefore the total number of  acceptable arrangements is 15*6! = 10800.

Answer (score 0):

$20-6+1 = 15$

Why +1 ? Read about the [fencepost problem](https://betterexplained.com/articles/learning-how-to-count-avoiding-the-fencepost-problem/)